# Printing Fixed document in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, printdialog, fixeddocument

I have a fixed document which contains 70 fixed pages approx.,
When I tried to print that fixed page by the below code, I got exception

code:

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
dialog.PrintDocument(FixedDocument.DocumentPaginator, "Print");
```

> Exception : Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the
>   program.

I thought of printing that 70 pages one by one, but I did not get any strike of the way though I surfed though google....Any way....?

Comment: What happens if you add ``dialog.ShowDialog();`` between the 2 statements and manually set the queue/``PrintTicket`` this way? There may be defaults getting set in the ``PrintDialog`` that you don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem you have here.  If you found a solution I'm interested in knowing it; and you should answer your own question if you did solve it.

As for printing pages one by one, here's something you could try.

```
PrintDialog dialog = PrintDialog();
var doc = FixedDocument.DocumentPaginator; 
for(int i = 0; i < doc.PageCount; i++)
{
    dialog.PrintVisual(doc.GetPage(i).Visual, "Page " + i);
}
```

This should answer the question, though I don't think I would follow this method since it'll send 70 individual print jobs to the printer.  Instead, figure out what's consuming all your resources using the `PrintDocument` call.